# Image not getting displayed in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know this question has been asked countless times.I also found many solutions but the image is not displaying.Getting error resource not found.I have done a fairly basic example.
Please help me.
i am new to spring

spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp">
</bean>
```

In display.jsp i have written the following code

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/a.jpg" />" />
```

I have created the resouces/img folder directly under WebContent.

The error  get in browser console

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:7070/SpringStaticDemo/resources/img/a.jpg

Thank u for the help in advance and sorry for asking such a basic question.

Comment: try to change your InternalResourceViewresolver with
  <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

Comment: @MaVVamaldo will try and let u know

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what was wrong.But I restarted Eclipse and now everything is working fine.It is showing the image. Don't know what happened.